# Splitting / Grouping DataFrame based on a date / time difference

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following rows in a dataframe:

| sender | receiver | bytes | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 50 | 2147483647 |
| C | D | 100 | 2147483648 |
| A | B | 150 | 2147483657 |
| C | D | 200 | 2147483658 |
| A | B | 550 | 2147487657 |

Each record/row in that dataframe contains the amount of data that has been sent between a sender and receiver within a 10s time window. The timestamps marks when that individual time window started.

Now, I want to compute the amount of data between every pair of sender and receiver within a "flow".
With a flow, I mean that data is continuously transferred between sender and receiver.
If for a longer period of time (say 1 hour) no data is transferred, I want the flows to be split. In the example above, I would like to get:

- flow_AB_1 = 200 bytes
- flow_CD_1 = 300 bytes
- flow_AB_2 = 550 bytes

flow_AB_2 would be a separate flow, as `2147487657 - 2147483657 = 4000` that is greater than `3600`.

Is there a way to achieve this with pyspark/Apache Spark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your issue you can:

- create a new column `flow` using the sessionization algorithm based on Spark's window described in [this blog post](http://www.janvsmachine.net/2017/09/sessionization-with-spark.html)
- group by `flow`, `sender` and `receiver` to sum `bytes`
- optionally, build your flows' names by concatenating `sender`, `receiver` and `flow` column

The complete code would be as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

window = Window.partitionBy('sender', 'receiver').orderBy('timestamp')

result = dataframe \
    .withColumn('flow_split', F.when(F.col('timestamp') - F.lag('timestamp').over(window) > 3600, F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0))) \
    .withColumn('flow', F.sum('flow_split').over(window)) \
    .groupby('sender', 'receiver', 'flow') \
    .agg(F.sum('bytes').alias('bytes')) \
    .select(
      F.concat(F.lit('flow_'), F.col('sender'), F.col('receiver'), F.lit('_'), F.col('flow') + 1).alias('flow'),
      F.col('bytes')
    )
```

With the input dataframe in your question, you will get the following result:

```
+---------+-----+
|flow     |bytes|
+---------+-----+
|flow_AB_1|200  |
|flow_AB_2|550  |
|flow_CD_1|300  |
+---------+-----+
```